Compiler errors with objects with string keys
I am working on a dictionary for an app that I want to turn multilingual. I have these types declared:
type SingleDictionaryEntry = {
    [key: string]: string
}

type Entry = {
    [key: string]: SingleDictionaryEntry | string
}

type Dict = {
    [key: string]: Entry
}

Then, the dictionary itself looks like this:
const Dictionary: Dict = {

    menu: {
        companies: 'Companies',
        clients: 'Clients',
        requests: 'Requests',
        sites: 'Sites'
    },

    companies: {
        list: 'Companies',
        new: 'Add New Company',
        edit: 'Edit',
        delete: 'Delete',
        table: {
            title: 'Title',
            type: 'Type',
            email: 'E-Mail',
            address: 'Address',
            city: 'City',
            telephone: 'Telephone',
            cellular: 'Cellular'
        }
    }

}

However, when accessing the translation like this:
const fields:Array<string> = ['title', 'type', 'email']
const dictionaryRoot:string = 'companies'

return (
    <>
    {
        fields.map((field) => (
            <strong>{dictionary[dictionaryRoot].table[column] ?? column}</strong>
        ))
    }
    </>
)

I get the error saying
Element implicitly has any 'type' because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'string | SingleDictionaryEntry'. No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'string | SingleDictionaryEntry'.

What am I doing wrong?

dictionary[dictionaryRoot].table can either be a string or a SingleDictionaryEntry, according to your types - if it was a string e.g. ""["title"] would make no sense so the compiler correctly tells you your code isn't type-safe. You need to narrow what you have.

So, if I understood correctly, instead of outputting the words from the translation object directly, I should wrap it in a function?

MRE: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyglgOwOYBsIBE4GNhwPYICGATiAKILClQC8UA3gFBQtQDaA1hCAFxQDOVREgC6fQcWGMAvo0YAzAK4Ic+BFAAmEALZ4AFBEqlxQ5FAA+sYWkyqCJckZAAaKF14DTSAJQNmUYghgRWJ1QyoQTm4RAG4ZRiA. You need the logic somewhere to deal with both possibilities.

Using typeof, the logic might look like this: if (typeof dictionary[dictionaryRoot].table === 'string') { // table is a string } else { // table is SingleDictionaryEntry }

Maybe this approach is what you're looking for? If so, hopefully one of the above commenters will post an answer or find a suitable duplicate question. If not, please [edit] to clarify.

Yeah I understand the use of the function to output, I was just thinking I overlooked something simple in TypeScript. Also, I just realized that the error is that "table" might be string, not table[column]?

Yes, dictionary[dictionaryRoot].table might be a string, as pointed out multiple times above. Is that not what you're expecting? Presumably dictionary is of type Dict, right? (There's no [mre] here so maybe we have it wrong.) Please [edit] to make sure we have a [mre] and then let us know if there's anything we're missing about this question.

No I was expecting that table[column] is error, not the table itself. Also, there is MRE created by @jonrsharpe above, I'll add it to my question.

I don't understand. What does "table[column] is error" mean? That is the error, because table might be a string.

@dkasipovic Please [edit] the question so that it's not answered inside the post. If you want to add an answer you can do so, but it should be an answer post.

To answer my own question:
Instead of creating problems with nested object, I decided to flatten the object at run time. Basically, that way my dictionary becomes
type Dict = {
  [key: string]: string
}

And then I can access translations like
dictionary['companies.form.type']

I used a flatten function found here, with minor adjustments: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-flatten-dynamically-nested-objects-in-order-in-typescript/
const flatten = (obj: any) => {
    let resultObj: Dict = {};

    for (const i in obj) {
        if (typeof obj[i] === 'object' &&
            !Array.isArray(obj[i])) {
            const tempObj = flatten(obj[i]);
            for (const j in tempObj) {
                resultObj[i + '.' + j] = tempObj[j];
            }
        } else {
            resultObj[i] = obj[i];
        }
    }
    return resultObj;
};

and changed my dictionary so it becomes
const Dictionary = () => flatten({
...
})

